# Testing a rails model with a singleton in a validate method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Very simple example:

Model:

```
require 'inventory'

class CustomerOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validate :must_have_at_least_one_item, :items_must_exist
  before_save :convert_to_internal_items


  attr_accessor :items

  after_initialize do
    #convert the internal_items string into an array
    if internal_items
      self.items ||= self.internal_items.split(',').collect { |x| x.to_i }
    else 
      # only clobber it if it hasn't been set yet, like in the constructor
      self.items ||= []
    end
  end

  private
  def convert_to_internal_items
    #TODO: convert the items array into a string
    self.internal_items = self.items.join(',')
  end

  def must_have_at_least_one_item
    self.items.size >= 1
  end

  def items_must_exist
    self.items.all? do |item|
      Inventory.item_exists?(item)
    end
  end
end
```

Inventory is a singleton that should provide access to another service out there.

```
class Inventory 

  def self.item_exists?(item_id)
    # TODO: pretend real code exists here
    # MORE CLARITY: this code should be replaced by the mock, because the actual
    # inventory service cannot be reached during testing.
  end
end
```

Right now the service does not exist, and so I need to mock out this method for my tests. I'm having trouble doing this the Right Way(tm). I'd like to have it be configurable somehow, so that I can put in the mock during my tests, but have the normal code run in the real world.

There's probably something I'm not wrapping my head around correctly.

EDIT: to be more clear: I need to mock the Inventory class within the validation method of the model. Eventually that will talk to a service that doesn't exist right now. So for my tests, I need to mock it up as if the service I were talking to really existed. Sorry for the confusion :(

Here's what I'd like to have in the specs:

```
describe CustomerOrder do
    it "should not accept valid inventory items" do
        #magical mocking that makes Inventory.item_exists? return what I want
        magic.should_receive(:item_exists?).with(1).and_return(false)
        magic.should_receive(:item_exists?).with(2).and_return(true)

        co = CustomerOrder.new(:name => "foobar", :items => [1,2]
        co.should_not be_valid
    end
    it "should be valid with valid inventory items" do
        #magical mocking that makes Inventory.item_exists? return what I want
        magic.should_receive(:item_exists?).with(3).and_return(true)
        magic.should_receive(:item_exists?).with(4).and_return(true)

        co = CustomerOrder.new(:name => "foobar", :items => [3,4]
        co.should be_valid
    end  
end
```

Using rails 3.0.3, rspec 2 and cucumber. Of course, only the rspec part matters.

Comment: I do not get what you mean... Had to be long night, wasn't it? Try to edit it a little, then give a sign it has clear questions.

Comment: I think you're very close here. Just replace `magic` with `Inventory`, so you're setting the expectation on the class. However there's a problem with the validation -- you need to add something to `errors` to get `valid?` to return false. Also, if I'm not mistaken `.all?` short-circuits, so the second `.item_exists?` would never be called -- reversing the order of the values returned by the stubs (true, then false) fixes this, but is somewhat opaque. Might want to add a comment there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this follows

Inventory class:

```
require  'singleton'

class Inventory 
  include Singleton

  def self.set_mock(mock)
    @mock = mock
  end

  def self.item_exists?(item_id)
    return @mock.item_exists?(item_id) if @mock
    # TODO: how should I stub this out for the api
  end
end
```

CustomerOrder model:

```
require 'inventory'

class CustomerOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validate :must_have_at_least_one_item, :items_must_exist
  before_save :convert_to_internal_items


  attr_accessor :items

  after_initialize do
    #convert the internal_items string into an array
    if internal_items
      self.items ||= self.internal_items.split(',').collect { |x| x.to_i }
    else 
      # only clobber it if it hasn't been set yet, like in the constructor
      self.items ||= []
    end
  end

  private
  def convert_to_internal_items
    #TODO: convert the items array into a string
    self.internal_items = self.items.join(',')
  end

  def must_have_at_least_one_item
    errors.add(:items, "Must have at least one item") unless self.items.size >= 1
  end

  def items_must_exist
    failed = self.items.find_all do |item|
      !Inventory.item_exists?(item)
    end
    if !failed.empty? then
      errors.add(:items, "Items with IDs: [#{failed.join(' ')}] are not valid")
    end
  end
end
```

CustomerOrder specs:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CustomerOrder do
    fixtures :all

    before do
        fake = double('fake_inventory')
        fake.stub(:item_exists?) do |val|
            case val
            when 1
                true
            when 2
                true
            when 3
                false
            end
        end
        Inventory.set_mock(fake)
        #GRR, skipping my fixtures right now
        @valid_order = CustomerOrder.new(:name => "valid order",
                                                             :items => [1,2])
    end

    it "should require a name and at least one item" do
        co = CustomerOrder.new(:name => "valid", :items => [1])
        co.should be_valid
    end

    it "should not be valid without any items" do
        @valid_order.items = []
        @valid_order.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should not be valid without a name" do
        @valid_order.name = nil
        @valid_order.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should expose items instead of internal_items" do
        @valid_order.should respond_to(:items)
    end

    it "should be able to treat items like an array" do
        @valid_order.items.size.should == 2
        @valid_order.items.should respond_to(:<<)
        @valid_order.items.should respond_to(:[])
    end

    it "should store items internally as a comma separated string" do
        co = CustomerOrder.new(:name => "name", :items => [1,2])
        co.save!
        co.internal_items.should == "1,2"
    end

    it "should convert items to internal_items for saving" do
        co = CustomerOrder.new(:name => "my order",
                                                     :items => [1,2])
        co.name.should == "my order"
        co.save!

        co.internal_items.should == "1,2"
    end

    it "loads items from the database into the items array correctly" do
        co = CustomerOrder.new(:name => "woot", :items => [2,1])
        co.save.should == true

        co2 = CustomerOrder.find_by_name("woot")
        co2.items.should == [2,1]
    end

    it "is not valid with items that don't exist" do
        @valid_order.items = [3,2,1]
        @valid_order.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "ensures that items exist to be valid" do
        @valid_order.items = [1,2]

        @valid_order.should be_valid
    end
end
```

This solution works, although it's probably not the best way to inject a mock into the Inventory Service at runtime. I'll try to do a better job of being more clear in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CustomerOrder do
  it "is invalid without an existing Inventory item" do
    item = mock('item')
    customer = Customer.new(:name=>"Moe")
    customer.stub(:items) { [item] } 
    Inventory.should_receive(:item_exists?).with(item).and_return(true)
    customer.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Note: untested.